# Change default camera to USB camera

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, usb, camera

I'd like to know how to change the default camera on Android to a USB camera, I'd like to use my webcam to authenticate QR codes, but with emulator, the camera doesn't start, I can only get video through a USB camera (v4l2)

> [image: Error opening the camera through app]

[image: It works on USB camera app]

I'd like to make WhatsApp recognize a USB camera.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WhatsApp only has access to camera id 0 and 1 (main rear camera and main front camera respectively). Further, the part where it scans QR code for Linked Devices it only uses camera 0 i.e. the main rear camera.

In short, the only possible way is to fake your external USB cam as camera 0 which is pretty hard (maybe build Android from source after making the necessary changes?) and since that's not my area of expertise, can't help further.