# Change default camera lens for all apps

Tags: rom-flashing, settings, camera, system, system-apps

I'm using realme x2 pro and have damaged my main camera lens (Because I mounted it on a bike holder) . I got it repaired once and it cost me about 15% of phone's value. But it got spoiled again.

However, the ultra wide lens and telephoto lens are working as they used to before and surprisingly are not damaged unlike main lens.

Since I'm not a photogenic guy I don't really want to spend more money on getting the main camera repaired again. However, I am not able to scan any QR codes and it's a big deal because of UPI payments everywhere. Also, it's impossible to use whatsapp web.

So I was wondering, and i haven't found the answer anywhere:

How do I change the default camera lens (preferable system level), so that when an app needs to scan something it uses the Ultra wide or telephoto lens?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible since some camera features/APIs may be proprietary to prevent other apps from using it.

Comment: What if I flash the phone with a new ROM? is there any light in that direction?

Comment: I guess that's one of the possibilities, though it also depends on how the ROM is configured (ref: [Change default camera to USB camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247172/44325))

Comment: So sorry to learn you aren't photogenic. :)